Sidebar shorthand for complex category types in Docusaurus
I'm trying to simplify the sidebar.js file on my Docusaurus project by using config shorthand. I've however reached a blocker as it seems that Docusaurus does not support shorthand for category types that are "doc links" or "Generated index".
Is that the case? Are there any known workarounds?

I don't think this is possible. Snippet from the Docusaurus docs:

Use the shorthand syntax when you don't need customizations

